# Lots of FAILURE AUDIT: an account failed to log on entires in Security Log

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I have received lots of failure audits on my server. From the log, I have identified the particular machine that is the culprit. How can I identify which process is sending the login request?

Do you have any idea how to find out?

Below is the detail of the log.

Security log on \QKSRVDC212:

```
[2465151] Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing

    Type:     FAILURE AUDIT 

    Computer: QKSRVDC212.Corp.abc.com

    Time:     7/26/2012 9:31:00 AM   ID:       4625 

An account failed to log on.
  Subject:
    Security ID:        S-1-0-0
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0
  Logon Type:           3

  Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        S-1-0-0
    Account Name:       Quality
    Account Domain:     QDMNT140

  Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xc000006d
    Sub Status:     0xc0000064

  Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

  Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   QDMNT140
    Source Network Address: 10.1.1.185
    Source Port:        3973

  Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

Answer (score 1):

On the login source system 'QDMNT140' use `netstat -ano | findstr 3973` to see which process has the matching source port '3973' open.  Replace 3973 with whatever the port changes to if it's not static.